# For each element returned by

Tags: jquery, apex

For each element returned by

```
{! followers }
```

one checkbox is created. I have a submit button, and 'on Submit' I want to record which checkboxes are and are not checked.

```
         <apex:repeat value="{! followers }" var="follower">
            $('#attendees').append(
                $('<div>').css('display','inline').append(
                    $('<input>', {type:"checkbox"}).addClass('myCheckBox').attr('id', '{! follower.subscriberId }')
                ).append(
                    $('<label>').text('{! follower.Subscriber.Name }')
                )
            );  
        </apex:repeat>
```

How would I pass the values from these check boxes to the submit button? I just want to alert() or console.log() them once they reach the submit button.

Something like this maybe?

```
            if ($('.myCheckBox').is(':checked')){
                alert($('.myCheckBox').attr(???))
            };
```

Or this?

```
           if ($('#attendees input').is(':checked')){
                alert($('#attendees input').attr('???'))
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a full list of values inside an array using the `.map()` function:

```
var cbValues = $(".myCheckBox").map(function() {
    return this.checked;
}).get();
```

Comment: Simple.  Beat me to it :)